# cannot import name 'int' from 'numpy'

Tags: numpy, pycharm, python-3.8

I was just getting started with PyCharm and python for statistics.
And I got this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'int' from 'numpy' (/home/tetiana/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py)

Full traceback looks like this:\
Traceback (most recent call last):\
File "/home/tetiana/forVScode/python/first/first_try.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy import stats\
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 379, in <module>
    from .stats import *\
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 180, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special\
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 643, in <module>
    from .basic import *\
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/special/basic.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import orthogonal\
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/special/orthogonal.py", line 81, in <module>
    from numpy import (exp, inf, pi, sqrt, floor, sin, cos, around, int,\
ImportError: cannot import name 'int' from 'numpy' (/home/tetiana/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I fix it?
Here is my code:

```
from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd

state = pd.read_csv('state_murder_rate_test_table.csv')
state['Population'].mean()
stats.trim_mean(state['Population'], 0.1)
state['Population'].median()
```

I checked whether the Python versions in os and in the project match and they are. I have python 3.8.10 and my os is Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Can't reproduce, maybe reinstall your environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the [current `numpy` documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/index.html), there exists no type called `numpy.int` that you can import. I believe that the type you wanna import is [`numpy.integer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.integer) or [`numpy.int_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.int_).

The code you provided does not have any statement like: `from numpy import int`. If you could provide a full traceback error, it'll be easier to see where the error stems from.

I hope this answer will be somewhat useful.

Comment: Looking at the traceback, it seems the error stems from the `scipy` module you're using. Maybe try installing a specific version of `numpy` that has an `int` module. My best guess is that `int` was available in previous versions of `numpy` and `scipy` used it, but `numpy` was updated and `scipy` still uses that depreciated module.

Comment: numpy 1.24 removed `np.int`.  Try updating your `scipy` version to match.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The root cause with your question may stem from a dependency management conflict between two software ecosystems. According to the error message, your numpy was installed using pip at the path `/home/tetiana/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/`. The scipy that depends on it was installed using apt at the path `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/`. The versions of the two are not compatible. In fact, there is a version of numpy in the system that scipy correctly depends on, but the Python interpreter prioritizes the numpy installed by pip, leading to this issue. There are typically two solutions to this problem: (1) Use pip to uninstall numpy and pandas, and then reinstall them using apt, or uninstall scipy using apt and reinstall it using pip. (2) Use Python's imp module to customize the path and import the numpy from the apt path before importing scipy. An example is as follows:

```
import imp
path = ['/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('numpy', path)
imp.load_module("numpy", fp, pathname, description)
```

Hope my diagnosis is helpful to you！